# Accessing the List-Property of a DataColumnCollection of a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumncollection

I am trying to access the **List**-Property of the **DataColumnCollection** of a **DataTable**, and it seems like there is none. The access is necessary, for there is a collection of strings ("**Format**") that I need to process after the extraction from the DataTable.

The documentation of Microsoft says, that it is accessible via the Columns of the DataTable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-6.0), but it isn't.

```cs
foreach (object item in dataTable.Columns.List)  // .List is marked as error
{
    Console.WriteLine("TEST: " + item.Format);   // .Format (is string) is marked as error
}
```

I know that the List-Property is at least getable and that's all I need. I believe that I'm missing something very obvious here... any Ideas?

Comment: Object doesn't have a format property. Use var instead of object, then item will have the actual type of what is in dataTable.Columns.List.

Answer (score 1):

DataColumnCollection is derived from InternalDataCollectionBase which itself is a collection, so your dataTable.Columns themselves is a list, you don't need to do columns.List

This is how you can access the properties of each column.

```
DataColumnCollection columns = table.Columns;

// Get the ColumnName and DataType for every column.
foreach(DataColumn dataColumn in columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dataColumn.ColumnName);
    Console.WriteLine(dataColumn.DataType);
}
```

Comment: Probably easier to say "because the class is a microsoft one with a name that ends in Collection, it should have an enumerator.." - because these classes are ooooold and implemen t IEnumerable, not IEnumerable<T> they give their elements out as objects, and the compiler writes a cast when it munges the foreach into the iterating expression.. Which is why `foreach(var x in datatable.Columns)` doesn't work immediately (x becomes object and must be cast)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use linq

```
var dtColumn = from item in dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
select item.ColumnName;
```

Comment: Ugh, this really doesn't need LINQ

Comment: (but it'd be reasonably expected to work if a DataColumn had a Format property)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found the Answer:

```
foreach (TableColumn item in dataTable.Columns) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("TEST: " + item.Format);  
}
```

Seems like the type **TableColumn** inherits from **DataColumn** and the property **Format** can be directly accessed.

Comment: This will work if the datatable.Columns collection does contain a TableColumn instance (whatever that is; neither the  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.TableColumn, nor  System.Windows.Documents.TableColumn seem to inherit from DataColumn, nor do they contain a Format property)..

Comment: Incidentally, without knowing that you've filled your datatable with some unknown type TableColumn which has a Format, we wouldn't have been able to arrive at a helpful answer.. If you do stuff that's non-standard, let us know so we can target the advice

Comment: Will do @CaiusJard. I wasn't aware that it would be non-standard. Thx for contributing.